# CSS/CSS3 to switch positions of elements

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have 4 columns in desktop view for HTML.
When we switch to mobile view, we show 2 columns and 2 rows (Please see attached image for reference).

The code is:

```
<div class="sections">
    <div class="one-fourth-col">Column 1</div>
    <div class="one-fourth-col">Column 2</div>
    <div class="one-fourth-col">Column 3</div>
    <div class="one-fourth-col">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

The view I get in mobile version is:

[image: View I get in mobile version]

I want following view:

[image: View required]

Basically, I want to show #1 and #2 in First column in left side. 
And #3 and #4 in second column on right side.

I am using float: right property in css.
I want to handle this by NOT moving the elements in HTML.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HashemQolami - It could also be done with multi-column layouts or even - in IE only - with grid layouts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using [CSS Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox) is an option, you could simply achieve that by [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)ing the flex items on mobile screens (via `@media` queries):

**[Example Here](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/ausJL)**

```css
.sections { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }

.one-fourth-col {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .one-fourth-col {
    flex: 1 48%; /* Actually it should be 50%
                    but there's a margin of 1%
                    around the columns, hence 50%-2(1%) = 48% */
  }

  .sections > :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
  .sections > :nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
  .sections > :nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
  .sections > :nth-child(4) { order: 4; }
}
```

*(vendor prefixes omitted due to brevity)*

For vendor prefixes click on *"Toggle Compiled View"* in the demo (Thanks to Autoprefixer).

At last but not least, if you're not familiar with [CSS Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox) you could refer to the following resources:

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox *(The spec is your friend!)*
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://weblog.bocoup.com/dive-into-flexbox/

Comment: Check this out! JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/po3g65xs/10/) or [Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/po3g65xs/10/show/)

Comment: @MaryMelody +1 Nice job! I wasn't thinking about that approach at the time of writing.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it by css `transform` and `@media` queries: - not very elegant but works just fine.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/po3g65xs/12/) or [Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/po3g65xs/12/show/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sections">
    <div style="background-color: #ADFF2F;" class="one-fourth-col div-1">Column 1</div>
    <div style="background-color: #0066FF;" class="one-fourth-col div-2">Column 2</div>
    <div style="background-color: #FFA500;" class="one-fourth-col transform div-3">Column 3</div>
    <div style="background-color: #FF00FF;" class="one-fourth-col transform div-4">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.sections {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.one-fourth-col {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .one-fourth-col {
        float: none;
        width: 40%;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .transform {
        -webkit-transform: translate(100%, -200%);
        -moz-transform: translate(100%, -200%);
        -ms-transform: translate(100%, -200%);
        -o-transform: translate(100%, -200%);
        transform: translate(100%, -200%);

        margin-left: 15%; /* 3 X Value of div-1 and div-2 margin-left */
    }
    .div-1 {
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
    .div-2 {
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-top: 50px; /* margin between rows */
    }
    .div-3 {
        margin-top: -50px; /* negative value of .div-2 margin-top */
    }
    .div-4 {
        margin-top: 50px; /* same value of .div-2 margin-top */
    }
}
```

**MORE INFO - CSS Transforms:**

> - http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform